# How can I get IBM's API token?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I need an API token to use IBM's real hardware(greater than 5 qubits) in Qiskit, where can I find the price?

Comment: You can try to sign up for the "IBM Quantum for Researchers" program https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/researchers-program/

Answer (score 0):

You can get your IBM API token by logging into your [IBM account](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com) or generate new token on [Account setting overview](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/account). You can copy it from there and use it locally on your computer to access the IBM devices.

[image]